# Python: Playing a music in the background?

Tags: python, pygame, playback

I am currently making a game in Python. I am not using PyGame, just the console (non-GUI)
When you start the game, you will get the logo to the game, and a lot of information about the "journey" you just started. There is a lot of text, so while the text is scrolling, I want to have a song played in the background.

I start the music with the following code:

```
def new_game():
    import winsound
    winsound.PlaySound("intro.wav", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
    LVL1_INTRO()
```

The only problem is: it won't continue to LVL1_INTRO() until the music have stopped playing. It's a problem, as the music is approximately 1-2 minutes long.

Is there any way to fix this? After the music have started, it will continue with LVL1_INTRO()

If it is possible, I would be happy if there is a code for stopping the music as well, so I don't need to start cutting the music, and make it exactly the same lenght as the intro.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html#winsound.SND_ASYNC) you use the SND_ASYNC flag.

```
winsound.SND_ASYNC 
Return immediately, allowing sounds to play asynchronously.
```

To stop playing, call `PlaySound` with a `NONE` argument.

```
winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

Comment: It looks like `SND_ASYNC` can be used with `SND_ALIAS`, so "or" them together like so: `winsound.PlaySound("intro.wav", winsound.SND_ALIAS | winsound.SND_ASYNC)`

Comment: @FredLarson, I wasn't sure why the OP was using the SND_ALIAS option when the `intro.wav` doesn't look like a system sound.  He probably should be using `winsound.SND_ALIAS | winsound.SND_FILENAME` but when I tested my answer the `SND_FILENAME` wasn't necessary when pointing it at a wav file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with this module, but it looks as though you can play sounds asynchronously. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html and look at SND_ASYNC.