# python3 text based RPG, can I have an mpeg playing while the game is running?

Tags: python-3.x, mpeg

I am in the process of making a text based RPG using Python3 and would like to have background music playing while the program is running. I have three questions regarding the code.

1. Can I have a file such as an mpeg or mp4 running when the game is executed?
2. What types of music files will python run?
3. Where in my code do I tell python to open and run the file? I assume right after the module imports but I'd like a solid answer for reassurance.

   Thank you!

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929990/python-playing-a-music-in-the-background

Comment: do I have to include the operand to run the file in a function? Could I make it a global event?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play a Sound with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python)