# How do I play a sound in the background? (python 3.5.2 for windows)

Tags: python, audio

Here's my code:

```
import subprocess
import os

path_to_notepad = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Media Player\\wmplayer.exe'
path_to_file = 'C:\\Users\iceki_000\Desktop\\ayy.mp3'

subprocess.call([path_to_notepad, path_to_file])
```

So far, I have it so an audio file opens up with Windows Media Player. Is it possible to launch WMP as a background process, so the sound will play, but the window won't be visible?

Comment: do you have to use Windows Media Player? because there are modules like `winsound` and I know `pygame` has sound support

Comment: really anything that plays sound in the background

Comment: try `import pygame.mixer; def play(audio_file_path): pygame.mixer.Sound(audio_file_path).play()`

Comment: (pygame is probably not builtin on windows so run `pip install pygame`)

Answer (score 0):

if you installed **python for windows**, then you should have winsound module. The usage is simple and it has various flags to set when, how you want to play the song and stop it. haven't tested it as I am on Linux

```
              import winsound
              #to play the music
              winsound.PlaySound("filename",  winsound.SND_ALIAS)

              #to stop the music 
              winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_ALIAS)

              #to play music asynchronously
              winsound.PlaySound("filename",  winsound.SND_ALIAS | winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

reference:- https://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html#module-winsound

stackoverflow:- [Python: Playing a music in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929990/python-playing-a-music-in-the-background)