# How to play winsound.playsound('file.wav', 0) and have the next line of code executed?

Tags: python, winsound

I'm trying to make a super simple adventure print("") game, and I'd like to have music in the background.
This is my current code.

```
import time
import winsound

winsound.PlaySound('file.wav', 0)

print("Hello player! This is a simple project I'm working on as I am new to python!")
```

And the `print("")` story continues.

Currently, the playsound function works but the program won't execute the next line until the sound is fully done. How can I solve this?

Comment: You simply need to pass the winsound.SND_ASYNC flag for the function, there are multiple examples on stackoverflow: [python-playing-a-music-in-the-background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929990/python-playing-a-music-in-the-background)